# Nonlinear increase in logic utilization for FPGA design

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, synthesis

I am creating a design using the Altera Stratix V GX-series FPGA. For host device communication we are using the PCIe x8 interface.

The interface itself takes up 3,058 ALMs (out of available 234,720).

With 1 copy of a custom design unit, the number of ALMs jumps to 3,077, just 19 more. Therefore we should expect every other copy to take up 19 units right?

But when we compile with 4,096 copies of the same design unit, 6,282 ALMs are used up, which is much less than anticipated. **Why does it seem like logic utilization increases nonlinearly?**

Comment: Because the units have some common part, which is identical and is reused by all of them.

Comment: Synthesis tools are very good at finding and eliminating redundant logic.

Comment: Also, have you connected your interface to external pins? If not you may find that many of them simply get synthesized away. No connection equals not placed in FPGA. Check the RTL Viewer and see if it is all still there.

Comment: How are these 4096 units interconnected? Interconnect logic does not scale linear.

Comment: Each one is connected to a register which is connected to the PCIe interface.

Answer (score 1):

This smells like something could be wrong with your user logic that results in a lot of it being optimized away.  4096 of anything should take up a LOT of logic resources.  Does the 4096 element design function correctly on the actual FPGA?

Comment: Yes, it functions correctly!

Comment: In that case, your design must be extremely simple.  Simple enough that the synthesis engine can pack each instance into one ALM.  Comparing the interface alone and all 4096 instances, that's about 0.8 ALM per instance.  What are these units, anyway?